# Oracle query with subquery from another table in "SELECT"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table1, and table2. There are sevaral rows in table2 for ID from table1.
Example:
Table1 (ID, Name, Age):

```
543 | John | 15
321 | Doe  | 17.
```

```sql
SELECT SCORE 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE ID = 543
```

(many rows as response).

I need a query with some columns from table1, as well as first row in column from table2.

Something like that:

```sql
SELECT A.NAME NAME,
       A.AGE AGE,
       (SELECT SCORE
        FROM TABLE2 B
        WHERE A.ID = B.ID
        AND ROWNUM = 1) SCORE
FROM TABLE1 A,
     TABLE2 B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Note that using `ROWNUM = 1` could theoretically give you any of the correlated rows from `TABLE2`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" row in column SCORE from TABLE2 (for the ID you are looking at)? How are the rows ordered, so there can be a "first" row, a "second" row, etc.? That "order by" instruction should be included in the correlated subquery, and the filter by ROWNUM would have to be in an outer query, if "first" means anything other than "***any***" row.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a correlated subquery with no join:

```
SELECT A.NAME,
       A.AGE,
       (SELECT B.SCORE
        FROM TABLE2 B
        WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND ROWNUM = 1
       ) as SCORE
FROM TABLE1 A;
```

Let me note that there is no such thing as "the first row in a table".  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.  This returns a value from an arbitrary row.  It is offered here because you use the same logic in the question.

Comment: Thanks for instant reply. It works for me

Comment: Though this is a *working* answer, I'm always scared if I find this construct in the productive code... It is safe from `ORA-01427`and will deliver *some* data.

Answer (score 1):

Limit rows using `FETCH` as shown [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1). Before getting result, you may want to order data to get, for example, latest value.

```
SELECT A.NAME,
       A.AGE,
       (SELECT SCORE
        FROM TABLE2 B
        WHERE A.ID = B.ID
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
       ) as SCORE
FROM TABLE1 A;
```